# Ruby path to nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash, `@data` looking similar to the following:

```
{
   "calcData"   =>   {
      "coverStartDate"      =>"10/08/2011",
      ...
      "part"=>      [
         {
            "licenceYears"            =>"10",
            "licenceType"            =>"1",

            ...

            "@partname"            =>"ratingData"
         },
         {                
            "dob"            =>"26/01/1964",
            "age"            =>"47",

            ...

            "@partname"            =>"driver"
         },

         ...
      ]
   }
}
```

There are various more sections in the `part` bit with difference `@partname`s.

What is the best way to select one of these `@partname` bits:

e.g.:

```
@data["calcData"]["part <<< where @partname="ratingData" >>> "]["licenceYears"]
```

How can I represent this logic in ruby/rails?

Comment: -1 Your data is not a valid Ruby object. You have an extra array opening `[` and an extra hash closing `}`. Furthermore, The relevant key should be `" part"`, not `"part"` as implied in you "e.g.".

Comment: @sawa I have largely modified the actual hash. These were just a typos - I was more interested how to solve the problem - I have edited the post to make it valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query = 'driver'

@data["calcData"]['part'].select{|part| part['@partname'].eql?query}
 => [{"dob"=>"26/01/1964", "age"=>"47", "@partname"=>"driver"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```
part = @data["calcData"]["part"]
keys = part.keys.select{|key| part["@partname"] == "ratingData"}
values = keys.collect{|key| part[key]["licenceYears"]}
```

You can combine this into a one liner but it's not as easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Use Struct.

```
CalcData = Struct.new :coverStarDate, :part
calc_data = CalcData[ "10/08/2011",
                      { "licenceYears" => 10,
                        # etc.
                      } ]
```

And thus you rid yourself of the top level bracket reference, ad you'll be able to say:

```
calc_data.part["licenceYears"]
```